# Drag and Drop / text editing with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to ask a question about jquery. I am new to jquery and found some code to drag and drop a text. i want to input a text in text box get its value and then drag and drop the text written.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button:#Get").click(function () {
  
 $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());
  
    });
 
    $("button:#Reset").click(function () {
  
 $('#msg').html("");
 $('input:text').val("");
  
    });
 
    $("button:#Set").click(function () {
  
 $('input:text').val("ABC");
 $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());
  
    });

$(function() {
    $( "#msg" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
 
</script>
```

```html
<div style="padding:16px;">
 TextBox : <input type="text" value="Type something"></input>
</div>
 
<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button> 
<button id="Set">Set To "ABC"</button> 
<button id="Reset">Reset It</button>


<div id="msg" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

The problem is that these two scripts works in separate files perfectly. But i have to merge it in a single file. Please help

Comment: You mean you want to drag and drop text content of input alone...? I really don't think it's possible with `jquery ui draggable` in a straightforward way. You can only drag elements. But there might be work around to make it look the way we want. But in that case you need to explain way further than simply saying "I want to merge these two piece of code". reading [ask] might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Made changes to your selectors. If you wish to hide 1st draggable after the drop, just uncomment `$("#msg").hide()`

```
<div style="padding:16px;">
    TextBox : <input type="text" value="Type something"></input>
</div>

<button id="Get">Get TextBox Value</button> 
<button id="Set">Set To "ABC"</button> 
<button id="Reset">Reset It</button>


<div id="msg" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 1px solid">
  <p></p>
</div>
<br>
    <br>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 1px solid">
  <p>Drag and drop here</p>
</div>

$("#Get").click(function () {   
    $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());
});

    $("#Reset").click(function () {

    $('#msg').html("");
    $('input:text').val("");

    });

    $("#Set").click(function () {

    $('input:text').val("ABC");
    $('#msg').html($('input:text').val());

    });


    $( "#msg" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable").droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $text = $("#msg").text();
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html($text);
       // $("#msg").hide();
      }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ck1m7q1/3/